# Reverse GeoCoding Issues with OpenStreetMap/Nominatim

Tags: geocoding, openstreetmap, nominatim

I'm wondering what kind of sense these results do? Afaik, response is really strange. I get only the house number, I would expect getting full address, or least a city, county country or so.
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=0.01&lon=0.01&zoom=18&addressdetails=1
Only information returned is house number 4. {"house_number":"4"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [returned object](http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/287623881). It is located somewhere in the Atlantic Ocean and consequently can't have a full address. Not the response is strange but the object is. I will delete it.